# Get Variable name from Web Service

Tags: java, web-services

My Web service has this form:

```
  @GET
        @Path("/path")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        public makeSomethingXML(@NotNull @QueryParam("one") String one,
                    @QueryParam("two") String two,
                    @QueryParam("three") String three,
                    @Context SecurityContext context, @Context HttpHeaders headers, @Context HttpServletRequest request) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {

return something;

            }
```

If I make an exception to see if a parameter is null, how can I throw the exception dinamically saying the name of the variable, like this

throws nullException("Must introduce" +one);